Python Ping IPv4 and IPv6 from docker container
I am trying to ping IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from inside my docker container.
I already tried using ping3, that does not support IPv6
>>> from ping3 import ping
>>> v4 = ping("142.250.185.110")
>>> v6 = ping("2a00:1450:4001:831::200e")
>>> print(v4)
0.003611326217651367
>>> print(v6)
False

I also tried using multiping, that returns response times for invalid IP Addresses (e.g. 1.2.3.4 from inside my docker container
mp = MultiPing([server_address])
mp.send()
responses, no_responses = mp.receive(timeout)
print(server_address + " " + str(responses))
# 1.2.3.5 {'1.2.3.5': 0.004548549652099609}
# 1.2.3.4 {'1.2.3.4': 0.004738330841064453}

Is there a good and reliable way to ping IPv4 and IPv6 addresses including response times?

Have you checked that IPv6 works in the container? Docker needs to be configured for that.

@KlausD. yes, I have IPv6 and IPv4 enabled in docker. When I open a shell, I am able to use both ping4 and ping6 to query any domain.

I found a way to ping manually using scapy
from scapy.all import sr1, IP, ICMP, IPv6, ICMPv6EchoRequest, conf


def _ping_v4(address: str, timeout: int = 5) -> float:
    packet = IP(dst=address) / ICMP()
    start_time = time.time()
    response = sr1(packet, timeout=timeout, verbose=0)
    if response is None:
        return -1.0
    return (time.time() - start_time) * 1000


def _ping_v6(address: str, timeout: int = 5) -> float:
    packet = IPv6(dst=address) / ICMPv6EchoRequest()
    start_time = time.time()
    response = sr1(packet, timeout=timeout, verbose=0)
    if response is None:
        return -1.0
    return (time.time() - start_time) * 1000


